# JQuery colorbox iframe, hide bottom bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, colorbox

I'm using colorbox to display an Iframe of my website's sign up page. Like so...

[image]

As you can see at the very bottom of the Iframe there is a white bar where the close 'X' used to be. I've removed every part of the border I can see to understand exists... Here is my JQuery for that...

```
$("#cboxTopLeft").hide();
$("#cboxTopRight").hide();
$("#cboxBottomLeft").hide();
$("#cboxBottomRight").hide();
$("#cboxMiddleLeft").hide();
$("#cboxMiddleRight").hide();
$("#cboxTopCenter").hide();
$("#cboxBottomCenter").hide();
$("#cboxClose").remove();
```

As far as I can tell this should be everything.

Comment: It could be another element or even the iframe itself sticking out at the bottom. Would need to see the html and css in action....

Comment: if you want to remove the white bar then inspect element in you browser by `f12` function key and check which part contain white bar. and then customize to see how it can be remove. or post your `css` and `html` here

Comment: Post your colorbox initialization code

Answer (score 0):

Add

`$("#cboxLoadedContent").hide();`

to the end of your jquery.colorbox.js file.  :)

Used browser inspector and found it.